# Highlighting the current users comment

Tags: comments, users

I don't know if this is possible, I've searched around but came up short. Basically, I need that the current user who is commenting to see his comments slightly different than the rest.

I'm doing this for admins/moderators, but the thing is that all users see the highlighted comments made by admin/mod, where here I just want every user to see his comments as highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assumes that your theme is using `comment_class()`;

example (to be added to functions.php of your theme):

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'comment_class_logged_in_user' );

function comment_class_logged_in_user( $classes ) {
    global $comment;
    if ( $comment->user_id > 0 && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
        $logged_in_user = $current_user->ID;
        if( $comment->user_id == $logged_in_user ) $classes[] = 'comment-author-logged-in';
    }
return $classes;
}
```

requires formatting of the css class:

```
.comment-author-logged-in { }
```

I recently posted a [plugin version in my site](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/mark-comments-by-current-user).

Answer (score 0):

First, if you look at the comment classes, you will notice a class called `byuser`. That class is one of the default classes added by [`comment_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class). That is all you need. You can style that with CSS however you want.

If you theme is not using `comment_class` as it should be then...

Look in your theme's `comments.php` for a function named `wp_list_comments`. In [Twenty Twelve it looks like this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/comments.php#L37): `wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentytwelve_comment', 'style' => 'ol' ) );`.

That `callback` part is the important part here. If there is a callback in your theme's function call, that is what you need to alter. If there is no callback the WordPress default will be used so there should be no problem. `comment_class` should already be in use.

The theme should have a function named the same as that callback's value in the code above. For Twenty Twelve it is `twentytwelve_comment` which [is defined in `functions.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php#L301). That formats and displays the actual comment list. All you should need to do is duplicate/edit that function and add the `comment_class` function, [right around here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php#L317).